# Getting linking error when running make file

Tags: ocaml, z3, opam, oasis

I am completely new to OCaml, however, I have been given a finished project, which includes the use of the z3 SAT solver, to test and gather data from.  I installed everything through Opam however I am getting the below error.  I am working on Ubuntu 18.04.

That is I installed Opam, and OCaml 4.08.0 as it's switch and the packages z3, Zarith, and Menhir.  I am to setup all packages through Oasis (_oasis file being provided with the project).  I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53241789/z3-bindings-on-ocaml/53242481#53242481) as the developer warned me that there may be some issues with binding OCaml to z3.  When presented with this error  I tried to reinstall the switch as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727774/ocamlopt-linking-error-code-2), however to no avail.

These are the steps which I'm taking to compile the project:

```
    $ oasis setup -setup-update dynamic
    $ make
```

However this results in the below error:

```
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    File "caml_startup", line 1:
    Error: Error during linking
    Command exited with code 2.
    Compilation unsuccessful after building 57 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:16.
    E: Failure("Command ''/home/john/.opam/4.08.0/bin/ocamlbuild' src/utils/utils.cma src/utils/utils.cmxa src/utils/utils.a src/utils/utils.cmxs src/parsing/parsing.cma src/parsing/parsing.cmxa src/parsing/parsing.a src/parsing/parsing.cmxs src/definitions/definitions.cma src/definitions/definitions.cmxa src/definitions/definitions.a src/definitions/definitions.cmxs src/definitions/symbolic-controllability/symcontrollability.cma src/definitions/symbolic-controllability/symcontrollability.cmxa src/definitions/symbolic-controllability/symcontrollability.a src/definitions/symbolic-controllability/symcontrollability.cmxs src/main.native -use-menhir -yaccflag --infer -tag debug' terminated with error code 10")
    Makefile:7: recipe for target 'build' failed
    make: *** [build] Error 1
```

[_oasis file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Jk0NgkTIcJ1aOWA56wyK_n6ItbLtiPEp)
[_log file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17ctW5qN2y-ZKUaFSxXhUa8ZajSlX0Cv1)

Comment: Most likely this is because the z3 opam package is broken, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839246/installing-ocaml-api-for-z3-using-opam
You can just add `CClLib: -lstdc++` to your library/executable in `_oasis`. Though there are tons of other possibilities, where it can fail, so if it doesn't help then, please, provide your `_oasis` and `_build/_log` files.

Comment: Unfortunately this failed as predicted I hence added a link to the _oasis and _log files

Comment: The links are under restricted access, it is better to either put them here or a public gist.  You can anonymize them if you don't want your personal information to leak.

Comment: sorry forgot to adjust the share settings

Comment: thanks a lot worked brilliantly

Comment: future referencees kindly note that the command to be added to _oasis file should be CCLib: -lstdc++